# Fading out everything except the element that's being pointed by the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sort of like a "Lightbox 2" effect but only on the elements pointed by a mouse. I don't even know how to start. Any advice would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('*').fadeTo('fast',0.5).hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast',1);
    }, function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.5);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/vJQDx/

Comment: @Matt - No worries, happens to all of us :)

Comment: BTW, it would be **much** more efficient way to write this using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live)

Comment: @Matt - Thanks.  I thought that was a good suggestion, but then I tried it and it seems to make the whole thing kinda tweaky: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/chg37/

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [expose](http://flowplayer.org/tools/toolbox/expose.html) plugin? Might be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to fade out everything **except** the element that's being pointed by the mouse. Other answers here are showing how to fade *in* the hovered element, not fade out the non-hovered elements ...

Here is an answer that hits the point made in your question.

http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/ecJw8/

```
$(function() {
    $("img").mouseover(function() {
        $("img:not(:hover)").fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
    });
    $("img").mouseout(function() {
        $("img").fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
    });
});
```

Comment: You'd rather re-fade a large list of elements on every hover-out instead of fading a single element?